# Autowiring class with non SpringBoot managed constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot

As the question suggests, how do you `Autowire` a class with non SpringBoot managed   class as constructor args.

The following is a code block illustrating this:

```
@Component
class Prototype
{
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    private NonSpringBootManagedBean bean;

    Prototype(NonSpringBootManagedBean bean)
    {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
}

@Component
class PrototypeClient
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private void createNewPrototype(NonSpringBootManagedBean bean)
    {

        // This throws an error saying no bean of type NonSpringBootManangedBean found
        Prototype prototype = context.getBean(Prototype.class, bean);
    }
}
```

The reason I am using `ApplicationContext` to obtain an instance of `Prototype` instead of using `@Autowired` is because I need a new instance of `Prototype` within the method `createNewPrototype()` every time it's invoked and not a singleton instance (Also, please advise if this way obtaining a new instance is incorrect).

Update:
As others have stated to move my creation of bean to a Java configuration class and adding method annotated by `@Bean` and instantiating the `NonSpringBootManagedBean` in the `@Bean` method. But I think this is not possible as this `NonSpringBootManagedBean` is passed by caller of `PrototypeClient.createNewPrototype()`.

**Update**
I have updated my above code example with a more clarity. Please refer this now.

```
@Component
class Prototype
{
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    // Here Session is part of javx.websocket package and cannot be added as part of 
    // Java configuration class with a @Bean annotation
    // In this case how can I use constructor injection?
    private Session session;

    Prototype(Session session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }
}

@Component
class PrototypeClient
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private void createNewPrototype(Session session)
    {
        Prototype prototype = context.getBean(Prototype.class, session);
    }
}

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/resources")
class WebSocketController
{
    private PrototypeClient client = ApplicationContext.getBean(PrototypeClient.class);

    @OnMessage
    void handleMessage(Session session, String message)
    {
        client.createNewPrototype(session);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want a new instance of your bean **every single time** you actually need to use method injection and the prototype scope : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection. Literally every call to your getter method will make spring create a new instance for you.
This is necessary because the prototype scope on it own will only create new instances for **every reference**, meaning : injected instances in fields will _(of course)_ keep the old instance

Comment: Do you want to handle _WebSocket_ messaging with SpringBoot? This is described in some articles like this: [Real-Time Communication: Implementing Websockets With Spring Boot](https://keyholesoftware.com/2017/04/10/websockets-with-spring-boot/).

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that you can change your bean scope to be a prototype reference instead of a singleton. That way you can scope a single bean definition to any number of object instances.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

```
private NonSpringBootManagedBean bean = new NonSpringBootManagedBean();

@Bean
public Prototype getPrototype(){
  return new Prototype(bean);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this does not completely answer my question. How can you inject non-spring managed item in the constructor? Whats the solution for this?

Comment: You can do it the same way. Create a Bean definition somewhere for your bean and pass your non-managed bean to the constructor. Then you can autowire your Prototype class. And each time Spring @utowire's that class it will give you a new instance, as long as you mark the bean scope as a prototype.

Comment: What if I want to pass an already instantiated arg; in my code example `bean` to the constructor when creating the `Prototype` object? I think this is not possible. In this case I think I have to set the variable by calling a setter after construction. But this is not really clean solution because if the arg in question is crucial for the functionality of the class then setting it after construction may lead to invalid state.

Comment: You can still do that, unless I'm misunderstanding you. In your @Bean method just supply that already instantiate variable to the bean. As long as you instantiate that variable outside the scope of your bean declaration then it will reuse it for each instance of your class. I edited my initial answer to try and make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry I am not following. Where is does this above code block reside with context to my question? Is it part of `PrototypeClient` class?

Comment: That code block should be in a class marked @Configuration somewhere. So that Spring knows how to create your Prototype bean. Then you can Autowire your prototype class and you'll get a new instance each time; just remember to declare the scope as prototype.

Comment: Mate I know you are trying to help. And I am glad I am receiving help from you. But it's really counter-productive when you provide partial answers. In this case I was already lost. The document you shared was about Spring not SpringBoot. Please bear in mind most people here are beginners and wont be able to understand some stuff unless clearly stated. Nevertheless thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189125/discussion-between-vino-and-adam).

Comment: this answer has got nothing to do with the prototype scope - its actually demonstrating how one would provide custom beans to the container and since the method always uses the keyword `new` every reference will receive a new instance ... making it comparable to the prototype `scope` but still very different

Answer (score 0):

Spring can not Autowire an Object if it is not aware of it. Some where there need to be @Component or @Bean or some other annotation like @Service etc to tell spring to manage the instance .

Also it is suggested that  if you are using a private variable in Autowire it should be part of constructor(for constructor injection ) or a setter method must be provided(setter injection)

To solve your error : you can create a java config class and place it in you base pkg (same as @SpringBootApplication or add @ComponentScan("pkg in which config is present") on class with @SpringBootApplication)

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    public class myconfig {

        @Bean
        public NonSpringBootManagedBean nonSpringBootManagedBean()
        {
            return new NonSpringBootManagedBean();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have a link or reference to this? I would like to read further to understand this? I tried googling and all I get is XML based Spring configurations instead of Springboot.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java

Also this 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: Also this https://www.journaldev.com/21033/spring-configuration-annotation

Comment: Could you please look at my new code example? In this case how can constructor inject `Session` which part of a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

### Define a bean with scope *prototype*

That is each time injected as *new instance*.
In **SpringBoot** you can use the *annotation* `@Scope("prototype")` to your bean class `Prototype`.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class Prototype {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    private NonSpringBootManagedBean bean;

    Prototype() {
        // you can only modify this 'NonSpringBootManagedBean' later
        // because Spring calls constructor without knowing NonSpringBootManagedBean  
        this.bean = new NonSpringBootManagedBean();

        // do something with 'repository' because its defined
    }

    public void setNonSpringBootManagedBean(NonSpringBootManagedBean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;        
    }        
}
```

### Use instances of this bean

Via injection (e.g. `@Autowired` to constructor) you can use different instances of this prototypical bean within other beans.

```
@Component
class PrototypeClient {
    // ApplicationContext still used?
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private Prototype prototypeInstance;

    @Autowired  // injects the new instance of Prototype
    public PrototypeClient(Prototype p)
        this.prototypeInstance = p;

        // here you can change the NSBMB
        modifyPrototype();
    }

    private void modifyPrototype(NonSpringBootManagedBean bean) {
         this.prototypeInstance.setNonSpringBootManagedBean( new NonSpringBootManagedBean() );
    }
}
```

### Why is your exception thrown?

> no bean of type NonSpringBootManangedBean found

Spring complains when trying to instantiate the bean of type `Prototype`

```
Prototype prototype = context.getBean(Prototype.class, bean);
```

because for calling its constructor it needs to pass an argument of type `NonSpringBootManagedBean`. Since all this bean-instantiating is done internally by Spring(Boot), you can not intercept and tell Spring: "Hey, use this bean of class NonSpringBootManagedBean" like you tried in method `createNewPrototype(NonSpringBootManagedBean bean)`.

### Why could'nt the `NonSpringBootManagedBean` be managed as bean by Spring(Boot)?

**Autowiring** in SpringBoot is a way of *dependency-injection*. This means a bean has been previously instantiated by SpringBoot, automatically at startup (when Spring boots). And this bean is now injected as dependency into another bean, etc. because this other bean depends on it.

If you tell us some more background, we could possibly bring light into your situation. This can be some answers to:

1. What is **NonSpringBootManagedBean** and why is it no *managed bean*?
2. What is **Prototype** and for which purpose does it use *NonSpringBootManagedBean*?
3. What is **PrototypeClient** and why does it create its own *Prototype* ?

I am not sure if I have understood the relationship and purpose between your objects/classes.

Comment: Hey man. I have added a better code example to answer the questions you have asked. In my case, `NonSpringManagedBean` is `Session` which part of `javax.websocket` package. Why does `PrototypeClient` create `Prototype` - for every session created via the web socket I need a new `Prototype` thats why.